# LL(1) grammar and first & follow sets

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, context-free-grammar

I think the below is actually LL(1) but I am not 100% sure. are we able to prove that this iss LL(1) grammar and then also, is the first and follow sets given correct? I dont really understand for sure how to actually get the follow sets.

Grammar

> expr        ::= term {addop term} 
>   term    ::= factor {mulop factor} 
>   factor     ::= variable| unsigned-number| ( expr)
>    variable ::= identifier 
>   addop ::= + | - 
>   mulop ::= * | /

First Sets

> First(expr) = identifier, unsigned number, ( 
>   First(Term) = identifier, unsigned number, ( 
>   First(Factor) = identifier, unsigned number, ( 
>   First(Variable) = Identifier 
>   First(addop) = +, - 
>   First(mulop) = *, /

Follow Sets

> Follow(Expr) = First(term) 
>   Follow(Term) = First(Factor) 
>  
>   Do not understand how to do the Follow sets of the below sets 
>   Follow(Factor) = First( ")" ) = ) 
>   Follow(Variable)
>   Follow(addop)
>   Follow(mulop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIRST sets are correct.

FOLLOW sets:

```
FOLLOW(A) of non-terminal A is the set of terminal symbols that can follow in the derivation sequence
```

FOLLOW(expr): check where it appeared in the right-hand side of production.
It is there is factor:=(expr), when we take this production in the derivation what follows expr is ) and expr is a start symbol.

```
   FOLLOW(expr)={),$}
```

similarly,

```
   FOLLOW(term) = FIRST(addop) U FOLLOW(expr) = {+,-,),$}
   FOLLOW(factor) = FIRST(mulop) U FOLLOW(trem) = {*,/,+,-,),$}
   FOLLOW(addop) = FIRST(term) = {identifier,unsigned number,(}
   FOLLOW(multop) = FIRST(factor) = {identifier,unsigned number,(}
   FOLLOW(Variable)= FOLLOW(factor) = {*,/,+,-,),$}
```

where $ is the end of the input.

Given grammar is  LL(1). FIRST sets of factor are disjoint and we don't need check the FOLLOW sets as there are no epsilon productions.

Comment: Okay, so o understand the fact that expr is basically term {addop term}* which means zero or more of {addop term}. How exactly can I use that production for a table when it is not setup in a way that is just expr -> term addop term or in the way of expr -> term?

Comment: Do you mean expr-> term {addop term}  as expr-> term | term addop trem

Comment: Nevermind. I have to do complete conversions from cfg to cnf which is out of scope for this question

Comment: Question is about FOLLOW sets, given all FOLLOW sets. why the answer was not accepted @Fel. Please post a separate question to fill the table I will answer it.